# Number of zeros outside the disk $\{ z : |z| \leq 2 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

I need to count (including the multiplicities of the zeros) number of the zeros outside the disk $\{ z : |z| \leq  2 \}$ for the polynomial

$f(z) = z^7 +9z^4 -7z +3$.

I know this should be direct application for Rouche's theorem, but I tried all choices for the two functions to get the required inequality $ |p(z)| < |q(z)|$ for $|z|=2 $, but none of them works. Should I consider a different curve or what terms I should consider to get the required inequality?

I think $z^7 +3$ should work but couldn't confirm that.

Comment: @JitendraSingh, I actually read this post before I wrote my question, and it  gives helpful hints, but the terms in my functions differ by 1 in the reverse directions.

Comment: The Theorem applies to zeroes _inside_ the disk, where $ \ 9z^4 + 3 \ $ dominates.  How many zeroes does that leave outside the disk?

Comment: @boojum, three !

Comment: @boojum, Wait! I think it does not dominate, because $|9z^4 +3| \geq 9|z|^4-|3| = 9 \times 2^4 -3 =141$ and $|z^7-7z|  \leq |z|^7 +7|z| = 2^7 +7\times2 =128+14 =144$.

Comment: The argument will require a little refinement, then, since $ \ 9z^4 + 3 \ $ does dominate even at $ \ |z| = \frac74 \ $ and $ \ |z^7 - 7z| \ $ only starts to "catch up" when $ \ |z| \ $ gets to about $ \ 1.85 \ $ .  The two are also close around $ \ |z| \approx 0.6 \ $ .  Four of the zeroes are inside the _unit_ disc and the moduli of the other three are all around $ \ 2.1 - 2.2 \ , $ which seems to be what makes the analysis a bit tricky.

Comment: @boojum, at $|z|=\frac{7}{4}$, $|9z^4+3| \geq 9(7/4)^4 - 3 =81.41016$ and $|z^7-7z| \leq (7/4)^7+7*(7/4)=62.52$ this implies that $f$ has 4 roots inside the circle $|z|=1.75$

Comment: Yes, that is what I was finding; a bit more beyond applying Rouché seems to be needed to show that there are _no more_ roots within a radius of $ \ 2 \ \ . $  What complicates this is that all of the other roots are _only slightly_ outside the disk in question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can apply Rouché's theorem to
$$
f(z) = z^7 +9z^4 -7z +3
$$
and
$$
g(z) = z^7 +9z^4 -10z = z(z^3+10)(z^3-1) \, .
$$
For $|z| = 2$ is
$$
|f(z)-g(z)| = |3z+3| \le 9
$$
and
$$
 |g(z)| \ge |z| (10 - |z^3|) (|z|^3-1)  = 28 \, .
$$
It follows that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros inside ($4$) and outside ($3$) of the circle $|z|=2$.

---

How did I find the comparison polynomial $g$? Trial and error, essentially, but here is a possible approach: Numerical approximations (e.g. with [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+z%5E7+%2B9z%5E4+-7z+%2B3+%3D+0)) indicate that $f$ has three roots with absolute value greater than two:
$$
\begin{align}
z_1 &\approx -2.14379 \\
z_2 &\approx 1.05711 - 1.84842 i \approx 2.12935 \cdot e^{-0.3346 i \pi }\\
z_3 &\approx 1.05711 + 1.84842 i \approx 2.12935 \cdot e^{0.3346 i \pi }
\end{align}
$$
These are – very roughly – the roots of $z^3+9.72$. This suggest to choose $g$ as $(z^3 + 10)$, multiplied with a fourth-degree polynomial having zeros only inside $|z|=2$. I chose the factor $z (z^3 - 1)$ so that in the difference $f-g$ both the $z^7$ and the $z^4$ terms vanish.

Comment: +1 Finding $g$ was only part of the solution, the way you lower bounded $|g(z)|$ a significant element.