# Using Rouché's theorem to find the number of zeros of $Z^8+5Z^7-20$

Tags: complex-analysis, roots, rouches-theorem

I am new to complex analysis and Rouché's theorem and would like to know if my choice of $f$ and $g$ are appropriate.

The version of Rouché's theorem I am most familiar with has the condition $|f(z)+g(z)|<|f(z)|+|g(z)|$, though I am aware of other forms of the theorem.

I've done a few examples with other functions, but the -20 term has thrown me off. I know there are plenty of examples on MSE but I could not find an example similar to mine.

I am trying to find the number of zeros of $h(z)=z^8+5z^7-20$ on the unit disk

I tried a few different combinations of the terms with no luck. One promising idea I had was to chose $f(z)=z^8+5z^7-20$ and $g(z)=-5z^7$. I believe this satisfies my inequality which implies $f(z)$ has 7 roots, but wolfram tells me it actually has 2 in the unit disk which I have no idea how to come to.

Any help or hints is appreciated. I understand these problems are often trivial but for some reason I cannot wrap my head around this problem with a large constant term.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $(-20)$ term is dominant in the unit disk: With $f(z)= z^8 + 5z^7 -20$ and $g(z) =20$ you have for all $z$ on the boundary of the unit disk
$$
 |f(z) + g(z)| = |z^8 + 5z^7| \le |z|^8 + 5 |z|^7 = 6 
< 20 = |g(z)| \le |f(z)| + |g(z)|
$$
which means that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros in the unit disk: *none.*

The same result can be achieved without Rouché's theorem: For $|z| \le 1$ is
$$
 |f(z)| = |z^8 + 5z^7 -20| \ge 20 - |z^8| - 5|z^7| \ge 20-1-5 = 14 > 0 \, .
$$

Comment: Thank you much, this makes me feel silly how simple it was and I couldn't see it.

Comment: Just so I'm clear, if I wanted to count the number of zeros in say the disk of radius 4, $5z^7$ would be the dominating term, and so $f$ would remain the same and set $g(z)=-5z^7$ thus $f$ has 7 roots? Anything bigger than radius 4 then $z^8$ would dominate and that would be my g, correct?

Comment: @Ralph: It is correct for radius $r=4$, but it does not work for (e.g.) $r=5$. There is not always a *single* dominating term, i.e. $g$ can not always be chosen as a monomial. Sometimes another “comparison polynomial” can be found (example: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4145049/42969), and sometimes Rouché's theorem does not help at all.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation this helped a lot.