# Finding the number of roots of $f(z) = z^5 + z^3 + 3z + 1$ in the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots, quintics

> Suppose we have  $$f(z) = z^5 + z^3 + 3z + 1$$ Find how many roots this function has in the open unit disc $\{z : |z| < 1\}$.

---

Here's what I think about it:

I tried to split $f$ into two functions $$g(z) = z^5 + z^3$$ $$h(z) = 3z + 1$$ and use [Rouché's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem) (to prove that $f = g + h$ has only one root). But $|h(z)| > |g(z)|$ has some troubles on unit circle (at least at $-1$ point).

Is there any way to use Rouché's theorem here? Maybe we can use it twice or  work around problems at this point? Have no idea how to fix it.

Comment: Do you agree with my edits?

Comment: You can show the is a single real root, in $(-1,0).$ Since the product of the roots is $-1,$ you can show that at most one of the complex conjugate root pairs is in the unit disk. Not sure where to go from there, though. There are either 3 such roots or 1 such root.

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the [symmetric version](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rouch%C3%A9%27s_theorem#Symmetric_version) of Rouché's theorem to $f(z) = z^5+z^3+3z+1$ and $g(z) = 3z+1$: On the boundary of the unit disk is
$$
|f(z) -g(z)| = |z^5 + z^3| \le 2 \le |g(z)|
$$
with equality only for $z=-1$. But $f(-1) \ne 0$, so that
$$
|f(z) -g(z)| < |f(z)| + |g(z)|
$$
everywhere on the boundary of the unit disk. It follows that $f$ and $g$ have the same number of zeros in the unit disk.

Comment: +1. Out of interest, what would have hinted to you to choose $g$ to be $3z+1$ as opposed to a different function?

Comment: @FShrike: Because it worked :) – Seriously: $3z+1$ is what OP already tried, so I demonstrated how to make it work. Generally you choose a “part” of $f$ which “dominates” the function on the boundary of the domain. $g(z) = 3z$ would probably work as well.

Comment: @FShrike: But it is not always possible to just “pick one or two terms” from a polynomial which dominate the other terms. Here is an example where Rouché can be applied, but the choice of the comparison function is not so obvious: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4145049/42969 (I apologize for the self-advertisement :)

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation

Answer (score 0):

Let me give you a hint-

Show that the conclusion of Rouche's theorem holds when we replace the condition $\vert f \vert <  \vert g \vert$  on $  \partial  \Omega $
with the condition $\vert f \vert \le  \vert g \vert$  on  $  \partial  \Omega $
and $ f+g \neq 0$ on $  \partial  \Omega $