# Rouche’s Theorem?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, rouches-theorem

This is from an exam meant for high-school students:

> Suppose $z$ is a complex number satisfying $z^5+z^3+z+3=0$. Then |z| satisfies: A. $|z|\lt 1$ B. $|z|\geq 1$ C. $|z|\leq \frac12$ D. $|z|\leq \frac13$

Now, the solution is pretty simple. Either you recognise that $-1$ is a solution to the equation so option B is the only feasible option, or you just notice that if $|z|\lt 1$ then $|z|^5+|z|^3+|z|\lt 3$ which is a contradiction. 
 However, I want to use Rouche’s Theorem because I view it as a more powerful tool than the ones that are currently provided to us and want to be able to use it if required. I do not, at all, understand the conditions required to be satisfied for the theorem to hold, but I (hopefully justifiably) assume that the conditions hold true for polynomials. I also think that in choosing f(z) and g(z), we must keep in mind that f(z) must have 5 roots in the disc $|z|\leq 1$ so that all roots of $f(x)-g(x)$ satisfy $|z|\leq 1$. So basically I need help in choosing the two polynomials f(z) and g(z).

Comment: For what it's worth, I question whether your goal of trying to use (for example) Rouche's theorem is advisable.  I notice in my Complex Analysis textbook, which is intended primarily for undergraduate Math majors, that Rouche's Theorem is provided about two-thirds of the way through the book.  If it was me, I would not try to surgically learn that specific item.  Instead, I would find some book that featured Rouche's theorem, and attack the book, starting from page 1.  This would allow me to develop a better fluency in Complex Analysis before I was exposed to Rouche's Theorem.

Comment: If you want I can write an intuitive explanation for it.

Comment: @EthakkaappamwithChai I’d love to see that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $f(z)=3$ and $g(z)=z^5+z^3+z$. Then $|z|=r<1\implies\bigl|g(z)\bigr|<\bigl|f(z)\bigr|$ and therefore Rouché's theorem tells us that $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros at the open disk with center $0$ and radius $r$. But $f$ has no zero there and $f(z)+g(z)=z^5+z^3+z+3$. So, $z^5+z^3+z+3$ has no root with absolute value smaller than $1$.

Comment: Isn't $|g(z)| = 3 = |f(z)|$ for $z=1$?

Comment: @MartinR use triangle inequality

Comment: Ah thanks @JoseCarlosSantos, I now see that I was thinking the wrong way!

Comment: Just clarifying: So even if f has no zeroes in an unbounded set, even then f+g can have zeroes in that unbounded set?

Comment: @insipidintegrator:  If $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ on the boundary of the circle then $f$ and $f+g$ have the same number of zeros inside the circle. But (unless I am mistaken), $|g(z)| < |f(z)|$ does not hold for $z=1$. Therefore this solution is incomplete

Comment: @insipidintegrator Yes, it can.

Comment: And does the bounded set we consider  _have_ to be open? Couldn’t we take $|z|\leq 1$ instead of $|z|\lt 1$?

Comment: @JoseCarlosSantos  I think that to have the strict inequality on the boundary, you want to use a circle of radius $1-\epsilon$.

Comment: One can apply the *symmetic* version of Rouché's theorem, see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4448960/42969 for an example.

Comment: @MartinR I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Someone tell me please: why at |z|=1, we cannot have |g(z)|<|f(z)|  by triangle inequality?

Comment: At $z=1$, $\bigl|g(z)\bigr|=\bigl|f(z)\bigr|=3$.

Comment: Oh, I confused it for |z|=1. Thanks @JoséCarlosSantos